# Pass python list to c++ extension using boost python

Tags: c++, python, list, boost, vector

I'm trying to write a c++ extension to replace the following python function in order to speed up my program

The python function looks like the following

```
def calc_dist(fea1, fea2):
    #fea1 and fea2 are two lists with same length
    ...
```

I wrote the function using c++ and boost python like follows:

```
#include <vector>
#include <boost/python.hpp>
double calc_dist(vector<double>& fea1, vector<double>& fea2)
{
    int len = fea1.size();
    double s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<len;i++){
        double p=fea1[i];
        double q=fea2[i];
        ...//calculating..
    }
    return s;
}
BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(calc_dist)
{
    using namespace boost::python;
    def("calc_dist",calc_dist);
}
```

and compile the above cpp code into a .so file like

```
g++ calc_dist.cpp -shared -fPIC -o calc_dist.so -I /usr/include/python2.6 -lboost_python
```

and trying to use the .so in a python program, the import works fine, indicating the module can successfully imported.

However, whenever I pass two lists to the parameter to the function, python will give errors like

```
ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    calc_dist.calc_dist(list, list)
did not match C++ signature:
    calc_dist.calc_dist(std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >,
                        std::vector<float, std::allocator<float> >)
```

can any one help me how to solve this problem? i.e pass a python list to c++ extension using boost?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Use boost::python::list see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3761391/boostpython-python-list-to-stdvector)

Answer (score 12):

Why did you write a function accepting `std::vector` if you want it to operate on a Python list? They're different things.

Boost.Python exposes python lists as the [list](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/python/doc/v2/list.html) class.

So, your function should look something like

```
double calc_dist(boost::python::list fea1, boost::python::list fea2)
{
    boost::python::ssize_t len = boost::python::len(fea1);
    double s=0;
    for(int i=0; i<len;i++){
        double p = boost::python::extract<double>(fea1[i]);
        double q = boost::python::extract<double>(fea2[i]);
        ...//calculating..
    }
    return s;
}
```

it's not tested, but hopefully is close enough to get you started ...

Comment: I just put the example together from the online docs, so there should be enough information for you to make progress.

Comment: one would (perhaps naively) hope for an automatic conversion from a python list to a std::vector, no doubt.  this code is more than enough to get started, since it includes a correct C++ argument type, and the necessary extract.  thanks!

Comment: Why not automatic conversion to a `std::list`, or a `deque`, or something else? Python lists aren't vectors and don't behave like them.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your helpful answer, how about the performance of `boost::python::list`?

Comment: Probably depends what you're doing with it. As always, the best suggestion is to try it and see.

Comment: I am getting warning like the following: warning: ‘*((void*)&<anonymous> +24)’ may be used uninitialized in this function, when passing a boost::python list. How can I get rid of it?

Comment: By posting it as its own question, with the minimal code necessary to reproduce the warning. That sort of looks like it might be a lambda.